# UnsatisfiableError conda-forge 3.7

Tags: python, pip, package, anaconda, conda

I've been having trouble installing some packages with conda (on python 3.7 on Windows in a conda env). For example if I try install the shap package:

```
conda install -c conda-forge shap
```

I get

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda-forge/win-64::wincertstore==0.2=py37_1002
  - shap
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

It installs fine with pip. But how could I resolve the error to use conda instead?

Comment: conda-forge is currently undergoing a big migration to the new compiler infrastructure. wincertstore is already migrated (build number 1002 > 1000). shap seems to depend on scikit-learn, which is not yet migrated.

Comment: Thanks. So there's nothing to do but wait?

Comment: AFAIK, everything should be fine once https://github.com/conda-forge/scikit-learn-feedstock/pull/76 is done, and shap itself is migrated.