# Deciphering error message to understand package conflict

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

A coworker sent me a [yaml file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GdjnNuwVXzSebB8Ogy4Q3vCva7loN306) with information regarding the environment he uses to run his python scripts. When I try to install the packages with anaconda, I get this error:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - blaze==0.11.3=py27h5f341da_0
  - llvmlite==0.21.0=py27h6dad3f9_0
  - numpy==1.15.1=py27h1aa3f02_0
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How can I interpret this? Facially, the three listed packages do not seem to be in conflict. As suggested, by the error prompt, I can view more details with conda info, but I still can't see a conflict. However doing this:

```
conda info numpy==1.15.1=py27h1aa3f02_0
```

doesn't reveal any results whatsoever, which is suspicious. Why doesn't this display relevant information when there clearly is a [corresponding Numpy release](https://anaconda.org/intel/numpy/1.15.1/download/linux-64/numpy-1.15.1-py27h1aa3f02_0.tar.bz2) available?

yml copied below:

```
name: CENSORED
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - intel
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=0.5.0=py_0
  - astor=0.7.1=py_0
  - backports.weakref=1.0.post1=py27_1000
  - basemap=1.1.0=py27_4
  - basemap-data-hires=1.1.0=0
  - c-ares=1.14.0=h470a237_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.8.24=ha4d7672_0
  - certifi=2018.8.24=py27_1001
  - cftime=1.0.0=py27_0
  - conda=4.5.11=py27_0
  - eccodes=2.7.0=1
  - ecmwf_grib=1.26.1=h804cc2b_0
  - gast=0.2.0=py_0
  - geos=3.6.2=1
  - grpcio=1.14.1=py27hd60e7a3_0
  - h5py=2.8.0=py27h470a237_0
  - hdf4=4.2.13=0
  - jasper=1.900.1=4
  - libnetcdf=4.6.1=2
  - libprotobuf=3.6.1=hd28b015_0
  - linecache2=1.0.0=py27_0
  - markdown=2.6.11=py_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.6=py27_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py27_0
  - mock=2.0.0=py27_1000
  - netcdf4=1.4.0=py27_0
  - openblas=0.2.20=8
  - openssl=1.0.2p=h470a237_0
  - pbr=4.2.0=py_0
  - protobuf=3.6.1=py27hfc679d8_1
  - pygrib=2.0.2=py27_3
  - pykdtree=1.2.2=py27_1
  - pyproj=1.9.5.1=py27_0
  - pyresample=1.9.2=py27_0
  - pyshp=1.2.12=py_0
  - python-eccodes=2.7.0=py27_1
  - sgp4=1.4=py27_2
  - tbb=2019.1=h2d50403_0
  - tbb4py=2019.1=py27h2d50403_0
  - tensorboard=1.10.0=py27_0
  - tensorflow=1.10.0=py27_0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py_2
  - traceback2=1.4.0=py27_0
  - unittest2=1.1.0=py_0
  - xmltodict=0.11.0=py27_0
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py27h08a7f0c_0
  - alabaster=0.7.10=py27he5a193a_0
  - anaconda=5.1.0=py27_2
  - anaconda-client=1.6.9=py27_0
  - anaconda-navigator=1.7.0=py27_0
  - anaconda-project=0.8.2=py27h236b58a_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py27_0
  - astroid=1.6.1=py27_0
  - astropy=2.0.3=py27h14c3975_0
  - attrs=17.4.0=py27_0
  - babel=2.5.3=py27_0
  - backports=1.0=py27h63c9359_1
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.4=py27he8db605_1
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py27h5bc021e_2
  - backports_abc=0.5=py27h7b3c97b_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.6.0=py27h3f86ba9_1
  - bitarray=0.8.1=py27h14c3975_1
  - bkcharts=0.2=py27h241ae91_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blaze=0.11.3=py27h5f341da_0
  - bleach=2.1.2=py27_0
  - bokeh=0.12.13=py27h5233db4_0
  - boto=2.48.0=py27h9556ac2_1
  - bottleneck=1.2.1=py27h21b16a3_0
  - bzip2=1.0.6=h9a117a8_4
  - cairo=1.14.12=h77bcde2_0
  - cdecimal=2.3=py27h14c3975_3
  - cffi=1.11.4=py27h9745a5d_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py27hfa10054_1
  - click=6.7=py27h4225b90_0
  - cloudpickle=0.5.2=py27_1
  - clyent=1.2.2=py27h7276e6c_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py27h5cde069_0
  - conda-build=3.4.1=py27_0
  - conda-env=2.6.0=h36134e3_1
  - conda-verify=2.0.0=py27hf052a9d_0
  - configobj=5.0.6=py27_0
  - configparser=3.5.0=py27h5117587_0
  - contextlib2=0.5.5=py27hbf4c468_0
  - cryptography=2.1.4=py27h6697b16_0
  - curl=7.58.0=h84994c4_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py27hc7354d3_0
  - cython=0.27.3=py27hc56b35e_0
  - cytoolz=0.9.0=py27h14c3975_0
  - dask=0.16.1=py27_0
  - dask-core=0.16.1=py27_0
  - datashape=0.5.4=py27hf507385_0
  - dbus=1.12.2=hc3f9b76_1
  - decorator=4.2.1=py27_0
  - distributed=1.20.2=py27_0
  - docutils=0.14=py27hae222c1_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py27h502b47d_2
  - enum34=1.1.6=py27h99a27e9_1
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py27h75840f5_0
  - expat=2.2.5=he0dffb1_0
  - fastcache=1.0.2=py27h14c3975_2
  - filelock=2.0.13=py27h61a9c69_0
  - flask=0.12.2=py27h6d5c1cd_0
  - flask-cors=3.0.3=py27h1a8a27f_0
  - fontconfig=2.12.4=h88586e7_1
  - freetype=2.8=hab7d2ae_1
  - funcsigs=1.0.2=py27h83f16ab_0
  - functools32=3.2.3.2=py27h4ead58f_1
  - futures=3.2.0=py27h7b459c0_0
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0=haa9412d_0
  - gevent=1.2.2=py27h475ea6a_0
  - glib=2.53.6=h5d9569c_2
  - glob2=0.6=py27hcea9cbd_0
  - gmp=6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
  - gmpy2=2.0.8=py27h4cf3fa8_2
  - graphite2=1.3.10=hf63cedd_1
  - greenlet=0.4.12=py27hac09c53_0
  - grin=1.2.1=py27_4
  - gst-plugins-base=1.12.4=h33fb286_0
  - gstreamer=1.12.4=hb53b477_0
  - harfbuzz=1.7.4=hc5b324e_0
  - hdf5=1.10.1=h9caa474_1
  - heapdict=1.0.0=py27_2
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py27h5233db4_0
  - icu=58.2=h9c2bf20_1
  - idna=2.6=py27h5722d68_1
  - imageio=2.2.0=py27hf108a7f_0
  - imagesize=0.7.1=py27hd17bf80_0
  - intel-openmp=2018.0.0=hc7b2577_8
  - ipaddress=1.0.19=py27_0
  - ipykernel=4.8.0=py27_0
  - ipython=5.4.1=py27_2
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py27h89fb69b_0
  - ipywidgets=7.1.1=py27_0
  - isort=4.2.15=py27hcfa4749_0
  - itsdangerous=0.24=py27hb8295c1_1
  - jbig=2.1=hdba287a_0
  - jdcal=1.3=py27h2cc5433_0
  - jedi=0.11.1=py27_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py27h4114e70_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py27h7ed5aa4_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py27_4
  - jupyter_client=5.2.2=py27_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py27hc6bee7e_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py27h345911c_0
  - jupyterlab=0.31.5=py27_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.10.2=py27_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py27h682c727_0
  - libcurl=7.58.0=h1ad7b7a_0
  - libedit=3.1=heed3624_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc=7.2.0=h69d50b8_2
  - libgcc-ng=7.2.0=h7cc24e2_2
  - libgfortran=3.0.0=1
  - libgfortran-ng=7.2.0=h9f7466a_2
  - libopenblas=0.2.20=h9ac9557_4
  - libpng=1.6.34=hb9fc6fc_0
  - libsodium=1.0.15=hf101ebd_0
  - libssh2=1.8.0=h9cfc8f7_4
  - libstdcxx-ng=7.2.0=h7a57d05_2
  - libtiff=4.0.9=h28f6b97_0
  - libtool=2.4.6=h544aabb_3
  - libxcb=1.12=hcd93eb1_4
  - libxml2=2.9.7=h26e45fe_0
  - libxslt=1.1.32=h1312cb7_0
  - llvmlite=0.21.0=py27h6dad3f9_0
  - locket=0.2.0=py27h73929a2_1
  - lxml=4.1.1=py27hf71bdeb_1
  - lzo=2.10=h49e0be7_2
  - markupsafe=1.0=py27h97b2822_1
  - matplotlib=2.1.2=py27h0e671d2_0
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py27h0e7c7be_1
  - mistune=0.8.3=py27_0
  - mkl=2018.0.1=h19d6760_4
  - mkl-service=1.1.2=py27hb2d42c5_4
  - mpc=1.0.3=hec55b23_5
  - mpfr=3.1.5=h11a74b3_2
  - mpmath=1.0.0=py27h9669132_2
  - msgpack-python=0.5.1=py27h6bb024c_0
  - multipledispatch=0.4.9=py27h9b5f95a_0
  - navigator-updater=0.1.0=py27h0f9cd39_0
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py27he041f76_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py27hed7f2b2_0
  - ncurses=6.0=h9df7e31_2
  - networkx=2.1=py27_0
  - nltk=3.2.5=py27hec5f4de_0
  - nose=1.3.7=py27heec2199_2
  - notebook=5.4.0=py27_0
  - numba=0.36.2=np114py27he2868da_0
  - numexpr=2.6.4=py27hd318778_0
  - numpydoc=0.7.0=py27h9647a75_0
  - odo=0.5.1=py27h9170de3_0
  - olefile=0.45.1=py27_0
  - openpyxl=2.4.10=py27_0
  - packaging=16.8=py27h5e07c7c_1
  - pandas=0.22.0=py27hf484d3e_0
  - pandoc=1.19.2.1=hea2e7c5_1
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py27h428e1e5_1
  - pango=1.41.0=hd475d92_0
  - parso=0.1.1=py27h718acc2_0
  - partd=0.3.8=py27h4e55004_0
  - patchelf=0.9=hf79760b_2
  - path.py=10.5=py27hefe4bee_0
  - pathlib2=2.3.0=py27h6e9d198_0
  - patsy=0.5.0=py27_0
  - pcre=8.41=hc27e229_1
  - pep8=1.7.1=py27_0
  - pexpect=4.3.1=py27_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py27h09770e1_0
  - pillow=5.0.0=py27h3deb7b8_0
  - pip=9.0.1=py27ha730c48_4
  - pixman=0.34.0=hceecf20_3
  - pkginfo=1.4.1=py27hee1a9ad_1
  - pluggy=0.6.0=py27h1f4f128_0
  - ply=3.10=py27hd6d9ae5_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py27h1b593e1_0
  - psutil=5.4.3=py27h14c3975_0
  - ptyprocess=0.5.2=py27h4ccb14c_0
  - py=1.5.2=py27h203d672_0
  - pycairo=1.15.4=py27h1b9232e_1
  - pycodestyle=2.3.1=py27h904819d_0
  - pycosat=0.6.3=py27ha4109ae_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py27hefa08c5_1
  - pycrypto=2.6.1=py27h14c3975_7
  - pycurl=7.43.0.1=py27hb7f436b_0
  - pyflakes=1.6.0=py27h904a57d_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py27h4a8b6f5_0
  - pylint=1.8.2=py27_0
  - pyodbc=4.0.22=py27hf484d3e_0
  - pyopenssl=17.5.0=py27hcee3be0_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py27hf1513f8_1
  - pyqt=5.6.0=py27h4b1e83c_5
  - pysocks=1.6.7=py27he2db6d2_1
  - pytables=3.4.2=py27h1f7bffc_2
  - pytest=3.3.2=py27_0
  - python=2.7.14=h1571d57_29
  - python-dateutil=2.6.1=py27h4ca5741_1
  - pytz=2017.3=py27h001bace_0
  - pywavelets=0.5.2=py27hecda097_0
  - pyyaml=3.12=py27h2d70dd7_1
  - pyzmq=16.0.3=py27hc579512_0
  - qt=5.6.2=h974d657_12
  - qtawesome=0.4.4=py27hd7914c3_0
  - qtconsole=4.3.1=py27hc444b0d_0
  - qtpy=1.3.1=py27h63d3751_0
  - readline=7.0=ha6073c6_4
  - requests=2.18.4=py27hc5b0589_1
  - rope=0.10.7=py27hfe459b0_0
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.35=py27h14c3975_1
  - scandir=1.6=py27hf7388dc_0
  - scikit-image=0.13.1=py27h14c3975_1
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py27h445a80a_0
  - scipy=1.0.0=py27hf5f0f52_0
  - seaborn=0.8.1=py27h633ea1e_0
  - send2trash=1.4.2=py27_0
  - setuptools=38.4.0=py27_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py27_2
  - singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py27h9bcb476_0
  - sip=4.18.1=py27he9ba0ab_2
  - six=1.11.0=py27h5f960f1_1
  - snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py27h44e2768_0
  - sortedcollections=0.5.3=py27h135218e_0
  - sortedcontainers=1.5.9=py27_0
  - sphinx=1.6.6=py27_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py27h1512b58_1
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.0.1=py27hf906f22_1
  - spyder=3.2.6=py27_0
  - sqlalchemy=1.2.1=py27h14c3975_0
  - sqlite=3.22.0=h1bed415_0
  - ssl_match_hostname=3.5.0.1=py27h4ec10b9_2
  - statsmodels=0.8.0=py27hc87d62d_0
  - subprocess32=3.2.7=py27h373dbce_0
  - sympy=1.1.1=py27hc28188a_0
  - tblib=1.3.2=py27h51fe5ba_0
  - terminado=0.8.1=py27_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py27hc38d2c4_0
  - tk=8.6.7=hc745277_3
  - toolz=0.9.0=py27_0
  - tornado=4.5.3=py27_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py27hd6ce930_0
  - typing=3.6.2=py27h66f49e2_0
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1=py27h5062da9_0
  - unixodbc=2.3.4=hc36303a_1
  - urllib3=1.22=py27ha55213b_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py27h9e3e1ab_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py27hff10b21_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py27_0
  - wheel=0.30.0=py27h2bc6bb2_1
  - widgetsnbextension=3.1.0=py27_0
  - wrapt=1.10.11=py27h04f6869_0
  - xlrd=1.1.0=py27ha77178f_1
  - xlsxwriter=1.0.2=py27h12cbc6b_0
  - xlwt=1.3.0=py27h3d85d97_0
  - xz=5.2.3=h55aa19d_2
  - yaml=0.1.7=had09818_2
  - zeromq=4.2.2=hbedb6e5_2
  - zict=0.1.3=py27h12c336c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=ha838bed_2
  - icc_rt=2019.0=intel_117
  - intelpython=2019.0=2
  - numpy=1.15.1=py27h1aa3f02_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.1=py27_0
  - pip:
    - appdirs==1.4.3
    - backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
    - novas==3.1.1.4
    - novas-de405==1997.1
    - pyspectral==0.7.2
    - python-geotiepoints==1.1.5
    - satpy==0.8.4
    - tables==3.4.2
    - trollimage==1.5.3
    - trollsift==0.2.1

prefix: CENSORED
```

Comment: Can you post the environment.yml file here? The most likely problem is a conflict of the dependencies of these packages.

Comment: If `pypi` is your only source for packages I don't believe `blaze` 0.11.3 is available. Check with `pip install blaze==` which should list available versions. I suspect this isn't your issue because `conda`.

Comment: I shared the yml file (see the link in the original question)

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, and ideally a [mcve]. Please [edit] it to make it reproducible without relying on external sources.

Comment: Could it be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973918/unsatisfiableerror-conda-forge-3-7

Comment: As @tripleee said, please [edit] to include the file in this post

Comment: To see the yml file look here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GdjnNuwVXzSebB8Ogy4Q3vCva7loN306

Comment: @WarpedReality No, please put it in this post. What happens when that link breaks? Then this post is worthless, and can't help anyone. Please [edit] to put it in this post

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding what you and @tripleee wanted.